# create ranges from a list of numbers

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a list of numbers like this:

```
28
57
87
116
145
176
204
233
```

And I need to transform it to ranges, with names, and basically, each range corresponds to the 1st number up to the next number -1. like this:

```
type, range1=28-56
type, range2=57-86
type, range3=87-115
type, range4=116-144
type, range5=145-175
type, range6=176-203
type, range7=204-232
```

Any ideas on how to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'p{printf "type, range%d=%d-%d\n", ++r, p, $1-1} {p=$1}' file
```

```
type, range1=28-56
type, range2=57-86
type, range3=87-115
type, range4=116-144
type, range5=145-175
type, range6=176-203
type, range7=204-232
```

Comment: so nice, great job

Comment: Could you please explain how your `awk` command works? thanks

Comment: Variable `p` always keeps value from previous record and `printf` is executed for current record. `r` is just a counter that goes up by `1` every time.